# System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid validation of the user input

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid` which displays some properties.

User can select rounding rules for displaying values, e.g. for `double` - "Round half away from zero". In this case converted value for `1.5` will be `2`.

Converter works perfectly, but when user edits this property and type `2` for example - initial value (`1.5` rounded to `2`) won't be updated. It seems that PropertyGrid compares converted value (which is `2`) with new value and decides that value wasn't changed.

How can I change validation logic for the new values so that it compares initial value instead of converted?

Comment: It depends on implementation. How do you change 1.5 and show 2?

Comment: I have implemented CustomTypeConverter which is derived from TypeConverter. It accepts rounding rules selected by user. But, it works correctly. Problem appears when user edits property and enters value which matches to converted. In this case no event that property was modified appears.